# How to get Display Metrics in Native Android App

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have written a native android library which is being called by a Unity application. The application needs to access the DPI. Is there a way I can get this information from my native library? I can see there is a [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class in Java, is there something equivalent that I can access in C++?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a JNI call from Java side to native(c++) side and pass your width, height information as parameter to native method.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Also there is a good and simple example here :

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html

Comment: Usually I would have a Java app with javah generated functions providing the JNI environment but in this case there is only a Unity App (C#) talking to a Native App (C++). Is it possible to access the JNI enviroment from C++? Had a look through the links provided (thanks) but no mention.